# TextView set multiple string into a setText(int resid)

Tags: android, string, android-studio, textview, display

Good morning,

How can I put multiple string ressources inside the setText to display them in order ?

I have a layout with a TextView (id: TxtDisp) and a Button (id: NextSentence) that change the text when I click on it.

```
NextSentence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TxtDisp.setText(R.string.sentence_2);
        }
    });
```

Where or how can I put four to six string ressources to be display in order when the button is clicked ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the string resources in an array, and get the string from that. So add a class member to track the which sentence is next

```
private int nextSentenceId = 0;
```

then in `onCreate` use code like this

```
final int[] sentences = new int[]{R.string.sentence_1, R.string.sentence_2, R.string.sentence_3};

NextSentence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( nextSentenceId < sentences.length ) {
            TxtDisp.setText(sentences[nextSentenceId]);             
            ++nextSentenceId;
        }
    }
});
```

Make sure to catch when you are at the last sentence or you will get an array out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily when you hold these strings in an array or something and have a counter that hold which string is displayed right now like so 
in `onCreate()` method put your sentences in an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Integer> strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add(R.string.sentence1);
strings.add(R.string.sentence2);
strings.add(R.string.sentence3);
```

then on the button click you can use the counter and track which is selected

```
NextSentence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TxtDisp.setText(strings.get(count++));
    }
});
```

I hope this would help you